# Server 2016 recursive for all except 1 DNS record?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, internal-dns, windows-server-2016

We host our DNS on Route53. For one record, we need to provide a different IP internally. It's sort of split brain, except both brains aren't hosted on 2016.

Basically, *.example.com should use the Route53 records. stupidapp.example.com should return an internal IP instead of the Route53 record (which still has to work externally).

Can I do this with Server 2016 DNS policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to create a DNS zone on your server named for the FQDN you want to resolve internally and create a blank/empty A record in the zone for the host in question. All internal queries for this hostname will be answered by your internal DNS server while all other internal queries for abc.com will be resolved by Route 53. This has no bearing on external queries, they'll all be answered by Route53. See the images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: question asked 2 hours ago and we answer 30 seconds apart, lol

Comment: LOL............

Answer (score 2):

Yup, just add forward the zone (not 2016 specific)

```
Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone -Name "stupidapp.example.com" -ReplicationScope "Forest" -PassThru
Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA  -ZoneName "stupidapp.example.com" -AllowUpdateAny -IPv4Address "192.0.2.10" -TimeToLive 01:00:00
```

Replace `192.0.2.10` with the internal IP

Or in the GUI, just add a forward zone for the domain: `stupidapp.example.com` and add the A record for the IP.